# How to get the value you need?

Tags: python, pandas

There is here such problem in the answer it turns out so. But I want to see only ['Store 1'].  What need to do?

```
def answer_ups():
    import pandas as pd
    bla = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': 'Chris', 'Item Purchased': 'Sponge', 'Cost': 202.50},
                   {'Name': 'Kevyn', 'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Litter', 'Cost': 232.50},
                   {'Name': 'Filip', 'Item Purchased': 'Spoon', 'Cost': 100}],
                            index=['Store 1', 'Store 2', 'Store 3'])
    bla ['NewCost'] = bla ['Cost'] * 1.15  
    ququ = bla ['NewCost'].sort_values(ascending=False)
    return ququ [1:2]

answer_ups()
```

Answer (Store 1    232.875)

Comment: `ququ.index[1]`?

Comment: Looks like `bla.NewCost.nlargest(2).tail(1)` is a good starting point here...

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the 'Store 1' part, just return this `return ['Store 1', ququ['Store 1']]`

It will output : `['Store 1', 232.87499999999997]`

Answer (score 0):

```
print(type(ququ))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

as in the function `answer_ups()` **ququ** is `Series` so here is given some `Series indexing`.

```
>>print(ququ.index) 
Index(['Store 2', 'Store 1', 'Store 3'], dtype='object')
>>print(ququ.index[1])
Store 1
>>print(ququ[1])
232.875
>>print(ququ[1:2])
Store 1    232.875
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that at his point your ququ variable is

```
ququ = 
    Store 2    267.375
    Store 1    232.875
    Store 3    115.000
```

The first column are the indeces that you can access this way:

```
ququ.index[1] = 
    'Store 1'
```

and the second column are the NewCost values, that you can access this way:

```
ququ[1] = 
    232.875
```